# How do I speed up the loading of Audio files so the user is not waiting.

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, mixer

I am building a game that lets users remix songs. I have built a mixer (based upon the apple sample code MixerHost (creating an audioGraph with a mixer audioUnit), but expanded to load 12 tracks. everything is working fine, however it takes a really long time for the songs to load when the gamer selects the songs they want to remix. This is because the program has to load 12 separate mp4 files into memory before I can start playing the music.

I think what I need is to create a AUFilePlayer audioUnit that is in charge of loading the file into the mixer. If the AUFilePlayer can  handle loading the file on the fly then the user will not have to wait for the files to load 100% into memory. My two questions are, 1. can an AUFilePlayer be used this way? 2. The documentation on AUFilePlayer is very very very thin. Where can I find some example code demonstrated how to implement a AUFilePlayer properly in IOS (not in MacOS)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right - in this case a 'direct-from-disk' buffering approach is probably what you need. I believe the correct AudioUnit subtype is `AudioFilePlayer`. From the documentation:

> The unit reads and converts
>      audio file data into its own internal
>      buffers. It performs disk I/O on a
>      high-priority thread shared among all
>      instances of this unit within a process.
>      Upon completion of a disk read, the unit
>      internally schedules buffers for playback.

A working example of using this unit on Mac OS X is given in [Chris Adamson's book *Learning Core Audio*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848). The code for iOS isn't much different, and is discussed in [this thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2011/Nov/msg00041.html) on the CoreAudio-API mailing list. Adamson's working code example can be found [here](http://pastie.org/2820693). You should be able to adapt this to your requirements.

Comment: Chis's post on pastie is exactly what I needed. I got a test working using two tracks and now I am working putting it in to the larger project with 12 tracks. If you are trying to do the same thing, looks like you can turn the AUFilePlaer into an array and load each track that way.

Comment: creating an AUFilePlayer array with an array of nodes worked. I know have 12 tracks playing at the same time.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. The pastie is what I needed too!